# Can I shrink the 65k method limit in dex with Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

I'm developing a big application how has many libraries, I reached the 65k methods limit and I want to clean some libraries to shrink the methods size. Now I'm using proguard, but this take 5 minutes to compile! so, I need a method to clean before proguard  (like exclude with build.gradle or something like that) 
I'm trying to use something like this :

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.+'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms.drive'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms.games'

}
```

but it doesn't works , any idea?

Comment: I'm not aware that `exclude group` will remove individual classes or namespaces from a dependency. Here "group" refers to the artifact group AFAIK. Use [Jake Wharton's shell script](https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/6002797) to identify where your 65K method references are coming from, and try to replace libraries with more compact ones (e.g., Wire or micro-protobuf instead of protobuf).

Answer (score 1):

If you disable ProGuard's optimization step (-dontoptimize) and obfuscation step (-dontobfuscate), ProGuard may be fast enough for debug builds. The shrinking step can go a long way in reducing the number of methods.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be running into [GRADLE-2964](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2964) which occurs because Gradle is not using Zip64? This is fixed, according to jira, so maybe it works with a snapshot of Gradle.

Example using snapshot of Gradle 1.12:

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions-snapshots/gradle-1.12-20140327133732+0000-bin.zip
```

Then in whatever task that is zipping (extends from ZipTask) slap on this:

```
{
    ....
    zip64 = true
    ....
}
```